# Deleting an arbitrary chunk of a file

Tags: python, c, file-io

What is the most efficient way to delete an arbitrary chunk of a file, given the start and  end offsets? I'd prefer to use Python, but I can fall back to C if I have to.

Say the file is this

```
..............xxxxxxxx----------------
```

I want to remove a chunk of it:

```
..............[xxxxxxxx]----------------
```

After the operation it should become:

```
..............----------------
```

Reading the whole thing into memory and manipulating it in memory is not a feasible option.

Comment: Do you mean in-situ delete (brave), or do you mean copy relevant pieces to new file, rename old file, rename new file, remove old file (sane)?

Comment: @John I guess we'll go with the sane option, although the brave option shouldn't be completely discarded.

Comment: The "brave" option is challenging to implement.  And a dumb idea because you've destroyed the file in the process of updating it.  Any problems and you have no recovery.  Please don't consider the brave option as even rational.  If you want to make a backup before attempting the "brave" option, that **is** the "sane" option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best performance will almost invariably be obtained by writing a new version of the file and then having it atomically write the old version, because filesystems are strongly optimized for such sequential access, and so is the underlying hardware (with the possible exception of some of the newest `SSD`s, but, even then, it's an iffy proposition).  In addition, this avoids destroying data in the case of a system crash at any time -- you're left with either the old version of the file intact, or the new one in its place.  Since every system *could* always crash at any time (and by Murphy's Law, it will choose the most unfortunate moment;-), integrity of data is generally considered very important (often data is more valuable than the system on which it's kept -- hence, "mirroring" RAID solutions to  ensure against *disk* crashes losing precious data;-).

If you accept this sane approach, the general idea is: open old file for reading, new one for writing (creation); copy N1 bytes over from the old file to the new one; then skip N2 bytes of the old file; then copy the rest over; close both files; atomically rename new to old.  (Windows apparently has no "atomic rename" system call usable from Python -- to keep integrity in that case, instead of the atomic rename, you'd do three step: rename old file to a backup name, rename new file to old, delete backup-named file -- in case of system crash during the second one of these three very fast operations, one rename is all it will take to restore data integrity).

N1 and N2, of course, are the two parameters saying where the deleted piece starts, and how long it is.  For the part about opening the files, `with open('old.dat', 'rb') as oldf:` and `with open('NEWold.dat', 'wb') as newf:` statements, nested into each other, are clearly best (the rest of the code until the rename step must be nested in both of them of course).

For the "copy the rest over" step, [shutil.copyfileobj](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj) is best (be sure to specify a buffer length that's comfortably going to fit in your available RAM, but a *large* one will tend to give better performance).  The "skip" step is clearly just a `seek` on the `oldf` open-for-reading file object.  For copying exactly N1 bytes from oldf to newf, there is no direct support in Python's standard library, so you have to write your own, e.g:

```
def copyN1(oldf, newf, N1, buflen=1024*1024):
    while N1:
      newf.write(oldf.read(min(N1, buflen)))
      N1 -= buflen
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest [memory mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap). Though it is actually *manipulating file in memory* it is more efficient then plain reading of the whole file into memory.

Well, you have to manipulate the file contents in-memory one way or another as there's no system call for such operation neither in *nix nor in Win (at least not that I'm aware of).

Answer (score 0):

Try `mmap`ing the file.  This won't necessarily read it all into memory at once.

If you really want to do it by hand, choose some chunk size and do back-and-forth reads and writes.  But the seeks are going to kill you...